# Camera Cutting Off Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Main Camera in unity has this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 myPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.position = target.position + myPos;

    }
}
```

But when I play test the game this is the image I am getting:

[image: Unity Camera]

Here are my unity settings:

[image: Unity Camera Settings]

What could be causing this? If I remove the script from the Main Camera, everything displays as normal:

[image: Normal Camera View]

Comment: You're moving the camera with that script, so you're seeing a different view. if you were to set target to your camera and myPos to 0 you wouldn't see a change (but I doubt that's your goal)

Comment: I want the camera to follow the player but it seems maybe the way I have chosen isn't the best way? I was messing around with Occlusion Baking but I have removed that and the error is still there. I'm not sure how to move forward here. Attaching the camera as a child of the player works but it carries rotation which I don't want. Only X-Axis and Z-Axis following. I'm a little stumped!

Comment: Apologies, the error exists if it is added as a child node to the player

Comment: The easiest way to get that working is to use one of the default camera scripts since there's more to following a character than following from a static distance (and you might run into problems not using LateUpdate). But I'd start by making `target` and `myPos` public variables and sending them in the inspector (target should be the player and `myPos` should be the distance to the player)

Comment: I just had a play about with the clipping panes section and that has resolved it! By giving it a -50 Near value, it has eliminated the grey square. But now the lighting is different when the script is attached. There is flat lighting when no script is attached and then harsh when the script is attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a common gotchya is the NEAR and FAR settings are wrong.

LOOK at your own image you posted above:

[image]

change the "Near" to say .1 and see if that helps.

Note that almost certainly, also, you should just MOVE THE CAMERA BACK A BIT.

---

**DON'T use a big negative value for the Near value.** That's possibly what's causing your lighting problem.

Try your best to ensure the Light is NOT ATTACHED TO the camera, player or anything else.

In the first instance, ensure all your items are separate, not parent-child.

Note, you can simply adjust your "myPos" here ..

[image]

you do that while it is actually Playing.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems -26 is the number that I can see everything for the Near setting. any less and the grey creeps in. Also I have moved the camera really far back but it hasn't changed anything. Could this be because it is orthographic?